# When I answer, who is more important, the person who asked or the person who landed from Google?

Tags: discussion

As a practicing programmer, I prefer the latter, because I find it very irritating when I get to the question that is seemingly on my own problem only to find an answer that is chewing on the typos the OP made.

But it seems that the common approach is to nurse the OP, to ask them for the particular code they have and to give a specific solution to their particular case in favor of the more generic solution applicable to the larger audience. Judging by votes, this approach is much more appreciated by the community.

So which approach is right?

And, if the latter (at least combined with the former to satisfy both people), how can we encourage this kind of answer? How can we stimulate the audience to vote on the generic answers in favor of specific ones?

Comment: They are both equally important. The guy who asked is going to give you that +15 that doesn't count against the cap, and the guy who landed from Google is going to give you those upvotes that make you hit the cap even when you can't find anything decent to answer today.

Comment: So it's all about votes. How can I forget the cornerstone foundation of Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Comment: So I make sure that I cover the generic case (teaching how to fish) as well as fix the peculiarities of the question at hand (catching that one fish and cleaning it).

Comment: Well, it's all about doing a better job than the next answerer, and votes let me know I did a better job, right?